# Split values from variable into two fields

Tags: regex, perl, awk

I have a variable that has two values in it separated by a semicolon. I want to get one of these values into one variable, and the other into another variable. I'm trying to do so using:

```
my $firstField = `echo $line | awk -F; '{print $1}'`;
```

But it's getting interpreted extremely oddly. How best would I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is absolutely no need to involve any external tool here. Use perl!

```
my $firstField = (split(/;/, $line))[0];
```

The outer parentheses are required because of Perl's rule ["If it looks like a function call, it's a function call"](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfunc.html). Without the extra parentheses, The `[0]` is interpreted as a subscript of the function call (which is invalid), rather than as a subscript of the list that is returned.

Or if you prefer:

```
my ($firstField) = split /;/, $line;
```

This assigns the first value of the list returned by `split` to the variable.

Comment: @Borodin I've added some explanation - do let me know if you think it could be improved upon.

Answer (score 0):

You can get as many as you want with one split call:
if you want them in scalar variables, use

```
    my ($a, $b) = split(";", $inputstring); # add $c, $d, etc as you like to the list
```

or to get a variable number into an array use:

```
    my @parts = split(";", $inputsring);
```